# when hovering over an element, additional information appears that does not affect neighboring similar ones HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm learning html and css and unfortunately I encountered difficulty when hovering over divs with displaying hidden elements. It is necessary that when you hover over the card, its color changes (which has already been done), the card increases and the hidden element appears. But unfortunately, when I hover over the first card, the other cards also increase in size, although the hidden information on them remains hidden. The only solution I found is if you remove the display:flex from the .services_cards element, but then the entire display of these cards collapses, but then they do not increase when hovering over one of them. I tried and through nth-child I did not succeed. Please tell me how to solve this problem.
For a better understanding of the situation, it is better to watch in full screen mode, so my complexity will be more understandable.

```css
.services__cards {
  margin-top: 58px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}
.services__item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFF1F9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 56px 23px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.services__item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.services__item:hover {
  background-color: #F78BB6;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.services__item:hover .services__card-header, .services__item:hover .services__card-descr {
  color: #FFF;
}
.services__item:hover .services__learnmore {
  display: inline-block;
}
.services__card-header {
  margin-top: 38px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 72px;
  color: #56597A;
}
.services__card-descr {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #919299;
  text-align: center;
}
.services__learnmore {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: none;
}
.services__learnmore span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="services__cards">
          <div class="services__item">
            <img src="images/cards/card-icon1.png" alt="card-icon image">
            <h3 class="services__card-header">Design</h3>
            <div class="services__card-descr">a plan or drawing produced to show the look and function</div>
            <a href="/" class="services__learnmore"><span>Learn more</span><img src="images/cards/arrow.png" alt="arrow image"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="services__item">
            <img src="images/cards/card-icon2.png" alt="card-icon image">
            <h3 class="services__card-header">Development</h3>
            <div class="services__card-descr">Development is defined as the process of growth or new</div>
            <a href="/" class="services__learnmore"><span>Learn more</span><img src="images/cards/arrow.png" alt="arrow image"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="services__item">
            <img src="images/cards/card-icon3.png" alt="card-icon image">
            <h3 class="services__card-header">Branding</h3>
            <div class="services__card-descr">The marketing practice of creating a name, symbol or</div>
            <a href="/" class="services__learnmore"><span>Learn more</span><img src="images/cards/arrow.png" alt="arrow image"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="services__item">
            <img src="images/cards/card-icon4.png" alt="card-icon image">
            <h3 class="services__card-header">Illustration</h3>
            <div class="services__card-descr">An illustration is a decoration, interpretation or visual</div>
            <a href="/" class="services__learnmore"><span>Learn more</span><img src="images/cards/arrow.png" alt="arrow image"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, then you can simply resolve it by adding a height to your services__item css class:

```css
.services__item {
  height: 100%; /* Just add it here */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFF1F9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 56px 23px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```css
.services__cards {
  margin-top: 58px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}
.services__item {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFF1F9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 56px 23px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.services__item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.services__item:hover {
  background-color: #F78BB6;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.services__item:hover .services__card-header, .services__item:hover .services__card-descr {
  color: #FFF;
}
.services__item:hover .services__learnmore {
  display: inline-block;
}
.services__card-header {
  margin-top: 38px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 72px;
  color: #56597A;
}
.services__card-descr {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #919299;
  text-align: center;
}
.services__learnmore {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: none;
}
.services__learnmore span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

Working code snippet :
```

```html
<div class="services__cards">
          <div class="services__item">
            <img src="images/cards/card-icon1.png" alt="card-icon image">
            <h3 class="services__card-header">Design</h3>
            <div class="services__card-descr">a plan or drawing produced to show the look and function</div>
            <a href="/" class="services__learnmore"><span>Learn more</span><img src="images/cards/arrow.png" alt="arrow image"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="services__item">
            <img src="images/cards/card-icon2.png" alt="card-icon image">
            <h3 class="services__card-header">Development</h3>
            <div class="services__card-descr">Development is defined as the process of growth or new</div>
            <a href="/" class="services__learnmore"><span>Learn more</span><img src="images/cards/arrow.png" alt="arrow image"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="services__item">
            <img src="images/cards/card-icon3.png" alt="card-icon image">
            <h3 class="services__card-header">Branding</h3>
            <div class="services__card-descr">The marketing practice of creating a name, symbol or</div>
            <a href="/" class="services__learnmore"><span>Learn more</span><img src="images/cards/arrow.png" alt="arrow image"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="services__item">
            <img src="images/cards/card-icon4.png" alt="card-icon image">
            <h3 class="services__card-header">Illustration</h3>
            <div class="services__card-descr">An illustration is a decoration, interpretation or visual</div>
            <a href="/" class="services__learnmore"><span>Learn more</span><img src="images/cards/arrow.png" alt="arrow image"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: when i added height like u said, first child is a little bit bigger than other 3

Comment: I just ran the code without the height and they are not all of the same width. So adding this height element doesn't change anything for me. But you can also add a  width: 100% in the same .services__item class to make sure it takes all the div width. And in this case I checked and they all have the same size

Comment: i got it. Its bc of icon images. I got this layout from the figma community and it's not the perfect size. That's why these cards are not symmetrical.